NetworkManager and DHCP issues with WLAN on HP laptop running Gentoo
I'm running Gentoo.
I have a HP laptop with the touch screen. I put the default GNOME on it.
Problem was that Wayland didn't like touch screens.
So I did the update and put X on it.
Everything worked fine, until I saw that GNOME upgrade brought NetworkManager.
And so I tried to switch to using it.
Unfortunately that didn't work. My wlan0 interface failed to load.
Looking into dmrsg I saw
Ieee80211 phy0: Failed to add default virtual face

There is no debug output in the dmesg.
Next thing - I tried to switch back to using dhcpcd. But the same thing happened - I got exactly the same error.
Unfortunately, even after I tried to turn on the debugging printouts nothing printed.
I'm on the 6.6.21 kernel version right now.
I can provide more info if asked, just don't know what.
Does anybody know what could be the issue? And how to find the cause of the problem?
The laptop doesn't have a wired network jack so I can't get online.
Thank you.
EDIT: dhcpcd is definitely running:
ps aux | grep dhcp
root 1455 0.0 0.0 3100 2324 ? S Jul 04 0.00 dhcpcd [manager] [ip4] [ip6]

So it is definitely running.
The output of ifconfig is as follows:
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mcu 65536
    inet: 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6: ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeId 0x18<host>
    loop: txqueuelen 1800 (local loopback)
    RX packet 0 bytes 0 (0.0.8)
    TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0.8)
    

TIA!!
EDIT:
WaylandGnome /etc/init.d # lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
   Capabilities: [40] Secure device <?>
   Capabilities: [64] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [74] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev c8) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
   DeviceName: ATI EG BROADWAY
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics]
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39, IOMMU group 0
   Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
   Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
   I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
   Memory at f0c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
   Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
   Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
   Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
   Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
   Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
   Capabilities: [2c0] Page Request Interface (PRI)
   Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
   Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
   Kernel modules: amdgpu

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35, IOMMU group 0
   Memory at f0c60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
   Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
   Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 1

00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
   Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26, IOMMU group 1
   Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
   I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
   Memory behind bridge: f0b00000-f0bfffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
   Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
   Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
   Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
   Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
   Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
   Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
   Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27, IOMMU group 1
   Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
   I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
   Memory behind bridge: f0a00000-f0afffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
   Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
   Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
   Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
   Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
   Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
   Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 2

00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo Platform Security Processor
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3, IOMMU group 3
   Memory at f0c40000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128K]
   Memory at f0900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
   Memory at f0c6f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
   Memory at f0c6a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
   Capabilities: [50] MSI-X: Enable- Count=2 Masked-
   Capabilities: [5c] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
   Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features

00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 4

00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34, IOMMU group 4
   Memory at f0c64000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
   Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB XHCI Controller
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 5
   Memory at f0c68000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
   Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
   Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
   Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
   Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19, IOMMU group 6
   I/O ports at 2118 [size=8]
   I/O ports at 2124 [size=4]
   I/O ports at 2110 [size=8]
   I/O ports at 2120 [size=4]
   I/O ports at 2100 [size=16]
   Memory at f0c6c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
   Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [70] SATA HBA v1.0
   Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH USB EHCI Controller
   Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 7
   Memory at f0c6d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
   Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
   Capabilities: [e4] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00e0
   Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH SMBus Controller
   Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel, IOMMU group 8
   Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company FCH LPC Bridge
   Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 8

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 0
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 1
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 2
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 3
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9
   Capabilities: [f0] Secure device <?>

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 4
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 5
   Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
   Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 5, IOMMU group 1
   Memory at f0b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
   Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
   Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
   Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
   DeviceName: Intel WLAN Intel 7265NGWG.NVW Stone Peak 2 D0 ac 2x2 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB NGFF 2230 WW non-vPro
   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [Stone Peak 2 AC]
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37, IOMMU group 1
   Memory at f0a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
   Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
   Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
   Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number a4-02-b9-ff-ff-4a-8b-57
   Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
   Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
   Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
   Kernel modules: iwlwifi

WaylandGnome /etc/init.d # rc-update
               binfmt | boot                                   
             bootmisc | boot                                   
              cgroups |                                 sysinit
                devfs |                                 sysinit
               dhcpcd |      default                           
      display-manager |      default                           
                dmesg |                                 sysinit
              elogind | boot                                   
                 fsck | boot                                   
             hostname | boot                                   
              hwclock | boot                                   
              keymaps | boot                                   
            killprocs |                        shutdown       
    kmod-static-nodes |                                 sysinit
                local |      default nonetwork                 
           localmount | boot                                   
             loopback | boot                                   
              modules | boot                                   
             mount-ro |                        shutdown       
                 mtab | boot                                   
            net.wlan0 |      default                           
             netmount |      default                           
           ntp-client |      default                           
               procfs | boot                                   
                 root | boot                                   
         save-keymaps | boot                                   
    save-termencoding | boot                                   
            savecache |                        shutdown       
              seedrng | boot                                   
                 swap | boot                                   
               sysctl | boot                                   
                sysfs |                                 sysinit
             sysklogd |      default                           
 systemd-tmpfiles-setup | boot                                   
 systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev |                                 sysinit
         termencoding | boot                                   
                 udev |                                 sysinit
         udev-trigger |                                 sysinit

WaylandGnome /etc/init.d # cat /etc/conf.d/net
config_wlan0="dhcp"

WaylandGnome /etc/init.d # lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
amdgpu               9805824  16
i2c_algo_bit           12288  1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 amdgpu
ttm                    81920  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
drm_exec               12288  1 amdgpu
drm_suballoc_helper    12288  1 amdgpu
amdxcp                 12288  1 amdgpu
drm_buddy              16384  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              49152  1 amdgpu
drm_display_helper    159744  1 amdgpu
wmi_bmof               12288  0
video                  61440  1 amdgpu
wmi                    28672  2 video,wmi_bmof
iwlmvm                548864  0
vboxnetflt             32768  0
vboxnetadp             24576  0
mac80211             1089536  1 iwlmvm
vboxdrv               520192  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               458752  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211             1032192  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
efivarfs               24576  1

WaylandGnome /etc/init.d # uname -a
Linux WaylandGnome 6.6.21-gentoo #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Apr  3 15:27:22 CDT 2024 x86_64 AMD FX-9800P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux 


Is dhcpcd running?  What is the output from ifconfig?

@eyoung100, please see the edits.

If I'm remembering right (It's been awhile since I'm on a wired connection now), but I believe NetworkManager will start the dhcpcd process upon connecting.  That ifconfig output is part of the issue: The 80211 stack rides on the virtual device and the virtual device is created from the hardware listed in  the ifconfig output.  Since you only have the loopback listed, NetworkManager cannot properly start.  If your Wireless card is internal, please provide lspci.  If it's USB, use lsusb. When you emerged the upgrade, did you happen to upgrade  your kernel?

@eyoung100, you remember correctly.. However, I switch away from NW since it was not working. I can put it back, but it will not change anything. Now I did upgrade the kernel and as I wrote - everything worked fine after the upgrade. I will put lspci output in the OP in a sec.

@eyoung100, question edited with the info requested.

Did you happen to overwrite any network related files with etc-update?  You've loaded the modules correctly but I would start by resetting the connection according to the handbook and resetting WPA Supplicant
